# Return Non-Numeric Elements Only from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I have a dataframe created from a .CSV file. Each column should consist of numeric values only, however it can sometimes be a string ('>18','<5','CANCELED',etc.)

Before using pd.to_numeric to convert the columns to numeric and coerce the non-numerics, I'd like to create a new dataframe or dictionary which contains unique non-numeric values found in each column. This will help understand what sorts of non-numeric inputs we are receiving for our features to be used in one or more predictive models.

This seems like a fairly simple task, but I am fairly new to Python and having a hard time figuring it out.

So far I've reduced the dataframe down to only columns of dtype object which seems like a good first step and removed the majority of the columns that have all numeric values:

```
df = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
```

I'm thinking that I need to iterate over each element and apply some function using isnumeric() to create a new dataframe? Or a dictionary with each column name containing string values as key name and the dictionary value being a list of unique string values found in that column?

Any help on the most efficient way to tackle this is much appreciated.

Sample Dataframe:

```
FEATURE_1   FEATURE_2   FEATURE_3   FEATURE_4
1               1         <1.5        >3.4
Nan             2           2           4
4            CANCELED       3          4.5
1.34            2         <1.5         <2
```

Desired Output:

```
{'FEATURE_2':['CANCELED'],'FEATURE_3':['<1.5'],'FEATURE_4':['>3.5','<2']}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. Edited the initial post. Does this make more sense with an example of the dataframe data and the ultimate output I am trying to get to?

Comment: yup, looks a lot clearer now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to try and convert each item in each series to `float`. If successful, return `NaN`; otherwise, return the element.

Use `dropna` and `drop_duplicates` to remove convertible strings and duplicate items.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""FEATURE_1   FEATURE_2   FEATURE_3   FEATURE_4
1               1         <1.5        >3.4
NaN             2           2           4
4            CANCELED       3          4.5
1.34            2         <1.5         <2""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True)

# define float converter check
def converter(x):
    try:
        x = float(x)
        return np.nan
    except ValueError:
        return x

# use list comprehension to apply function and clean up
res = {col: df[col].apply(converter).dropna()\
                   .drop_duplicates().tolist() for col in df}

{'FEATURE_1': [],
 'FEATURE_2': ['CANCELED'],
 'FEATURE_3': ['<1.5'],
 'FEATURE_4': ['>3.4', '<2']}
```